Counting arborescences in time-inhomogeneous stationary markov chain
Problem:
Consider a directed graph G which is irreducible i.e. there is a directed path from any node to any node. For each $i$, let $S(i):=\{j:i\to j\}$ and $|S(i)|:=$ the cardinality of S(i). Let $\{X_n\}$ denote the markov chain on G with transition probabilities $p(j|i)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{|S(i)|}& j\in S(i)\\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. Let $\pi$ denote its stationary distribution. Show that the number of arborescences rooted at $i$ is proportional to $\frac{\pi(i)}{|S(i)|}$.
Note: The root of arborescence has no outgoing edges.
I am unable to proceed. Any hints are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.
